# Edison fuse no longer completing the circuit

Tags: electrical

A circuit blew, and friend tried to replace the fuse with one that had a lower amp rating. Did this twice, the fuse blew immediately. Now, I have replaced their fuse with the proper amperage (20) and now the circuit isn’t powering anything at all and also not blowing the fuse.

I removed the fuse from the Edison box, and I tested the contact with my multimeter (which has a 50amp fuse, so IT didn’t blow). The contact itself didn’t do anything, but for some reason when I accidentally touched this little metal ring about a centimeter off of the contact pad, my multimeter leads somehow completed the circuit and the lights flicked on.

Unfortunately, I can’t actually get one of the Edison fuses to complete the circuit.

Should I clean the contact pad? What is the next step, here?

PS: yes, I realize the whole thing should be replaced because an old Edison box has no place in a modern house with much greater loads on circuits, etc. Just trying to keep this running until they can afford to get the whole thing replaced and get the electricians to come out. We’re in an area where there is a shortage of qualified ones, and they are scheduled far out and charge a lot to bump you up in the queue.

Comment: I don't see a problem with a fuse box with normal loads. So what was the measured amps on the circuit, then?  Are you sure you know what you're doing? I've never heard of a multimeter with a 50A fuse that measured amps conductively (fuse wouldn't matter otherwise).

Comment: [Just don't do this like McGyver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2KTPmrT8xY)

Comment: Pictures are always good.

Comment: Test the fuse.  I know you should be able to see a bad fuse with your eyes, still test it.  If the screw in type, turn off the power and raise the centre tab a bit(and clean if dirty).  Make sure 20 amp fuse is the right size for that circuit.  Everybody with 15 amp fuses tripping upgraded to 20 amp.

Comment: Something blew the fuse. Now that something is also dead. Find it.

Comment: If fuse/breaker are blowing immediately, then that is a sign of a short.  Find and fix the short, then work on the fuse.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   I liked that show.  You mean I should not try all of his ideas?